# ZBar iOS Automatic Recognition

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, qr-code, zbar-sdk

in my ios application, I have implemented the zbar qr sdk code scanner into my application. The user scans a qr code, and the contents go to a text field(Non-Editable type).

What I was wondering, is there a way that I can make the app automatically opens safari (if qr code is a link), mail (if the qr code is an email), phone (if qr code is a phone #). If I did this, it would help the app become more automated and user friendly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the reader's `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method you can make decisions based on the data.  Define how you identify each data type and use a switch statement:

```
switch(dataType) {

  case ISLINK: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLfromString:parsedUrl]]; break;
  case ISEMAIL: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLfromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@",parsedUrl]]];
  ...
}
```

Comment: when i did that, it says "Use of undeclared identifier 'dataType'?

Comment: Don't take my snippet literally.  YOU need to determine what kind of barcode it is and set `dataType`.  Then you can use a switch to handle the appropriate action.